# How to debug SSL REST service Code which is POST

Tags: wcf, rest, visual-studio-debugging

I have a existing SSL based REST service whihc is deployed in my local IIS. I would like to debug the POST method in VS2012 code.

when I try locate w3p.exe under avaiable processes in Debug->attach to Process I couldnt find it. 
Not sure if i am doing anything wrong in it. I am running a test under the same solution which calls the following line of code

```
httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

The idea is, while running the test when above line of code hits which will essentially calling localhost REST service which source code is under the same solution and I have kept the break point in it so that when above line hits this will call REST based source code where i have kept break point.

But i couldnt find w3p worker process in the list. pls suggest. I have to do this as its a HTTPS REST service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noworries....I had to click on "All User" processs in order to see W3WP.EXE [IIS] process. it may help others...